# Does the formula $ V =\omega r$ holds in angular frequency

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, angular-velocity

$ V =\omega r$  can I use that formula if $\omega$ is angular frequency instead of angular velocity?

V is velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular frequency is the magnitude of angular velocity, so yes. Although as far as I'm aware, we typically only speak of angular frequency when the angular velocity (or speed) is constant.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity) refers to an “angular frequency vector”.

Comment: @Ghoster What I understand that to mean is "angular frequency (normally a scalar), vectorized". Wikipedia also defines [angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency) to be a scalar, and the magnitude of angular velocity.

Comment: Unfortunately the two articles aren’t consistent. Personally, I’ve always considered “angular frequency” and “angular velocity” to be synonymous. No distinction between them was drawn in any of my textbooks or by any of my professors.

Comment: @Ghoster It's entirely possible that these terms are defined/used differently/inconsistently by different authors. In my experience, angular frequency is more often used as a scalar in cases where there is a regular rotation with constant speed. I'm not sure what definitions SirMrpirateroberts is going by, but regardless, I think the answer to this question is "yes".

Comment: @Puk what about $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$ where w is angular frequency

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts That is the angular speed (magnitude of angular velocity) of an object undergoing uniform circular motion.

Comment: @Puk so that formual is valid ?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts $\omega=2\pi/T$ is valid for an object undergoing uniform circular motion.